# The "Paste" menu is disable, after copy the image data into clipboard

Tags: objective-c, macos

everyone:
I have a strange problem, when I copy the image to clipboard, and put the mouse into one textView, the "paste" menu is disable(Gray color). What does happen?

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];
NSArray *copiedObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image,nil];
[pasteboard writeObjects:copiedObjects];
```

while the image is one NSImage object.

After I do the action, I move my mouse to one textview, and right click my mouse, there is gray "paste" menu, which is as follow. Why the "paste" menu is disable? And if I open the TextEdit or Word, the "paste" menu will enable. Could anyone tell me what's worong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx2xr.png)

Comment: Did you switch on "Graphics" in IB?

Comment: what do you mean "switch on Graphics in IB"? I put the TextView on IB directly and do nothing else.

Comment: Select the text view (not its scroll view), go to the Attributes Inspector, find the check box "Graphics".

Comment: Yes!you give me the good answer~~thanks very much~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text view (not its scroll view), go to the Attributes Inspector, find the check box "Graphics".  – Willeke